# Silverstripe: Filter blog posts by Author

Tags: php, silverstripe

I've been googling for about 2 hours now and can't find an answer to this question. I'm trying to filter blog posts (using the silverstripe-blog module) by Author/MemberID. So far I've got:

```
public function MyRecentPosts() {

        $posts = BlogPost::get()
            ->sort('PublishDate','desc')
            ->limit(2);

        return $posts;
    }
```

Obviously that only returns the most recent blog posts. I'm not sure I understand how to relate the Blog Post table with the BlogPost_Authors table...

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well the `BlogMemberExtension` is applied to the `Member` class, which provides you with an easy way to access a member's posts via the "belongs many many" association.

I'm assuming here that this function would *not* be in an extension of Member, and that you'll pass in the member ID since it's not present in your code already. This assumption may well be incorrect since your method is named "**My**RecentPosts", but anyway - here's an example:

```
public function MyRecentPosts($memberId)
{
    $member = Member::get()->byId($memberId);

    $posts = $member->BlogPosts()
        ->sort('PublishDate', 'desc')
        ->limit(2);

    return $posts;
}
```

You could also do it from the `BlogPost` model via its "many many" association:

```
$posts = BlogPost::get()
    ->filter(array('Authors.ID' => $memberId))
    ->sort('PublishDate', 'desc')
    ->limit(2);
```

Comment: Fantastic. Thanks for your help.